# validate input boxes dynamically for whitespaces or if empty

Tags: javascript, validation

hi guys i have a bit of an issue i cant seem to tackle i need to validate the below code to make sure before a user updates each row from the table that's displayed. the data has not been deleted so its not empty or doesn't just contain white-spaces

how can i validate this using JavaScript to make sure the user hasn't deleted the data or hasn't just put white spaces in i will need to do this for about 20 results in the table so using a function would be awesome so no matter how many results are displayed each row is validated and can be update individually

```
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_staffmembers");
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
        {       
            echo "<tr><td><input type='text' value=' " .  $row2['staffmember_firstname'] . " '></td><td><input type='submit' value='Update'></td></tr>";                                                

        }
```

thanks for your help in advance i know how to create function so far everything i have tried will only allow me to validate the first row that's displayed i need to be able to validate and submit each row buy its self like a shopping cart updating the quantity 1 buy 1

just to be clear i have created the below i need to validate each row separately to make sure there is no white spaces or its not empty

http://jsfiddle.net/o7adxn7c/

Comment: If you're talking about a string you can call **.trim()** on the string. But I can't tell what your doing

Comment: check out the below i need to validate a table dynamiclly like that so when i submit each row it makes sure the user has not deleted the data so not empty or has no whitespace http://jsfiddle.net/o7adxn7c/

Comment: why do you have so many forms and using table layout seems like the right thing to do when first learning. But from experience I say save your time and go into learning your basic css **(cleaner markup)** if you use one form all you have to do is add the required attribute on the input elements

Comment: it already is cleaned up that's just and example

Comment: oh did you try using one form and the required attribute? also the pattern attribute takes a regex for the value of the input to match

Comment: the below code from mbomb007 works prefectly but i need to make sure it works in multiple browsers

Comment: I'm assuming your going to stick to that considering the below conversation. But your still looking for a different way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67270/discussion-between-edwin-and-nathan).

Comment: You should change your `<input ...>` tag to be `<input ... />`
This is for both `<input>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting the `pattern` attribute of the `input` element in the HTML. Using a pattern is advantageous since it prevents users from entering input that does not conform to the pattern provided.

A good regular expression to use: `pattern="^[^\s]+$"`
This regular expression ensures the entire input string contains at least one character, and it cannot contain whitespace characters.

In the JSFiddle code above, your `echo` line would become the following: `echo "<tr><td><input type='text' pattern='^[\S]+$' value=' " .  $row2['staffmember_firstname'] . " '></td><td><input type='submit' value='Update'></td></tr>";`. This uses the `\S` pattern instead of `^\s`. They should both work.

Here is a description of the attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Here is a tutorial on regular expressions: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Comment: In the above regular expression, `\S` could maybe be used instead of `^\s`. They are the same thing.

Comment: could you perhaps show me how i would use this in the above jsfiddle code

Comment: @Nathan If you still cannot get it to work, try looking at the first link I provided. They have a working example of the validation using `pattern`, and you can click their "Try it yourself" button to see it and modify it.

Comment: ok i just tried this, but it still allows me to submit the form if i delete the information in the value field

Comment: The regular expression should account for that, but if you need to, try adding the `required` property. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: Hmm. I tested it and you're right, it was allowing empty input for some reason. `required` fixed it.

Comment: changed some more bits of code and that is working perfectly does this work in multiple browsers im using chrome

Comment: @Nathan according to the first link I provided, it is not supported by Safari, but the others it should work.

Comment: interesting the page im developing they would be using on ipads so i might just give it a go on that and hope for the best is there any other methods you can think of

Comment: "Android, Safari and Mobile Safari support the pattern attribute, but do not support form validation, so will not prevent an incorrect value from being submitted"

Comment: awesome then you have answered my question :-) thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67271/discussion-between-nathan-and-mbomb007).

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try jQuery. Loop through each row i.e. $('#TableID').find('input').each(function.....